# How to get the class name of a ContentType in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-contenttypes

How do I get the class name in string of a ContentType? I tried it this way, but it didn't worked out:

```
class StreamItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    content_class = content_type.__name__

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.content_class
```

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** After a clarification of the problem which asks for the model name the way to access it is through the attribute `model`, you can access it in runtime in this way:

```
<STREAMING_ITEM_INSTANCE>.content_type.model
```

I tested it:

```
from testso_app.models import StreamItem
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
a = User.objects.all()[0]
cctt = ContentType.objects.all()
si = StreamItem(user=a, content_type=cctt[0], object_id=1)
si.content_type.model
```

and got: `u'author'`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can't I use it as an attribute?

Comment: I tried it. But its give me the name as `ContentType` and not the actual name of the model.

Comment: ok. But do you mean `content_class = content_type.__class__.__name__` or the one you wrote?

Comment: You asked by the class name, not model name, so I will edit the answer again

Comment: Yes, i dnt want to change the `content_type`, I just want the class name (`content_class`) by the `content_type`. ok. Will be waitin..

Comment: Thank you. But how do i implement it in the `StremItem` class to save the value (class name) in the `content_class`?

Comment: Add a property to the class that returns `self.content_type.model`

Comment: You mean, @property def class content: return self.content_type.model